# Echad Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On average it takes 161 Jewish months to become Bar Mitzva. 13 x 12 = 156 + 5 extra Adars.

Comment: That'd be, I suppose, both the mode and the ceiling of the average (mean), but obviously not the exact average (up arrow from me anyway  :-)  ).

Comment: @msh210 We deal in integers around here. This isn't the first time someone's shoehorned an answer into this series using floor or ceiling. How many days, for example, are in a month?

Comment: @Gershon, nice find!

Comment: @R'IM, I wasn't disputing or even frowning upon the answer (it _was_ a nice find), but merely pointing out the math in case someone didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

*R'u* was 161 was *Avraham* was born. (Source: [*Rashi* to *B'reshis* 19:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214/showrashi/true#v1920).)